# How do you reverse engineer a "constructed" AD attribute into its different parts?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Active Directory objects contain some [constructed](http://blogs.technet.com/b/efleis/archive/2004/11/17/258710.aspx) attributes that are made up of other attributes.

Using ADSI Edit, I can open the schema of my particular attribute in question (CN=ms-DS-Principal-Name,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,...) and look at the schema attributes, but I don't see anything in there that defines how it builds its value.  I would like to know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The logic for the attribute is hardcoded inside of AD. There's no definition in the schema that defines how the attribute is populated.

Comment: Does that mean that constructed attributes cannot be created?

Comment: Is that documented anywhere?  Being able to create constructed attributes sure would be handy.